# Pre-Generated Mapping Views

Tags: entity-framework

Segui esta simples [instrução](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469601.aspx) para criação do `Mapping Views`:

Sempre a primeira consulta no banco demora pois criação este `Mapping` né? Por isso a primeira a demora? Certo?
Eu criei ele da forma do fórum, mas mesmo assim demora a primeira consulta, deveria parar, não?

Até tentei "enganar" colocando no início do sistema um pesquisa Async:

```
using ( var ctx = new Contexto)
{
 var lista = ctx.Usuario.ToListAsync();
}
```

Mas esta consulta fica ali até terminar, e trava o layout.